# cumsum of values for same timeunit

Tags: matlab, cumsum

i have the following vectors:

```
A=[1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0];
B=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
```

in this case A represents a time vector, where the 1s signal the beginning of one time unit.
now i want to add up all the values in B which correspond to a time unit with the same length of 3 steps.
So in this example this would mean the 3rd, 4th and 5th value and the 8th, 9th and 10th value of B should be summed cause these are in a time unit of length 3.

```
B_result=[12 27];
```

i know cumsum() is the command for this but i dont know how to say that only these specific values depending on the time indices of A should be summed.

can you help me?

thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cumsum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) alongside [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`hist`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html):

```
csa = cumsum(A); %// from begining og unit to unit indices
n = hist(csa, 1:max(csa));  %// count num of steps in each unit
B_result = accumarray( csa', B' ); %// accumulate B into different time units
B_result(n~=3) = []; %// discard all time units that do not have 3 steps
```

Comment: i get an error for using accumarray:
Second input VAL must be a vector with one element for each row in SUBS, or a scalar.
i dont get it?

Comment: @user3858157 you might just need to transpose (`.'`) the inputs to columns - no need for `reshape`.

Answer (score 2):

```
N = 3; %// We want to detect a one followed by exactly N-1 zeros. Call that
%// sequence an "interesting part"
ind = find([A 1]); %// find ones. Append a last one to detect a possible 
%// interesting part at the end.
ind = ind(diff(ind)==N); %// index of beginning of interesting parts
cs = cumsum(B); %// accumulate values
B_result = cs(ind+N-1)-cs(ind-1); %// use index to build result
```

Comment: @Shai Thanks. I have added some comments

Answer (score 2):

For a simpler pattern matching, you can use `strfind`:

```
loc = strfind([A,1],[1 0 0 1]); %// add the 1 at the end of A and the pattern to avoid longer intervals
idx = bsxfun(@plus,loc,(0:2)'); %'// get the indices that need to be summed

result = sum(B(idx),1); %// obtain the result
```

Comment: @LuisMendo: regexp doesn't do doubles, but yes, if you convert to string first, you could probably craft a "beautiful" example with regexprep....

Comment: @LuisMendo: Ok, deleted my other comment as well. By the way: `regexprep(char(A+'0'),'10{2}','\b\b${num2str(sum(B(length($`)+(1:3))))}  ')` returns the correct result with the given input, but you can't convert it to a numeric result ;)

Comment: Could you check that? It gives me an error in Matlab 2010b, but it could be that it's too old a version

Comment: @LuisMendo: there is a tickmark after the dollar sign that gets swallowed by the markup language. Try this: regexprep(char(A+'0'),'10{2}','\b\b${num2str(sum(B(length($`)+(1:3))))}  ')

Comment: However, it is possible that some of the functionality of command expressions in regex have been added at a later date.

Comment: It must be my Matlab version. Its help doesn't say anything about this use of `$`. It seems to be a very powerful feature of `regexpregp`! I mean the ability to apply Matlab functions within

Comment: @LuisMendo: What you should already have is $1 etc to refer to the matches; $` and $' are the string preceeding and following the match, respectively, but these are new. ${cmd} does exist in R2010b. See dynamic regular expressions.

Comment: According to `help regexprep`,  I do have `$1`, but not the others. Another reason for me to upgrade :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo: Unless you get a service contract, I suggest you wait for R2014b.

Answer (score 2):

A more generic application of [Jonas' Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996736/2605073):

```
A = [1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1];
B = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12];

n = 3;

result = arrayfun(@(x) sum( B(x:x+n-1) ), strfind([A,1],num2str(10^n+1)-48))
```

or use `cumsum` instead of `sum`, I was not sure what you actually want:

```
result = arrayfun(@(x)  cumsum( B(x:x+n-1) ), ...
                       strfind( [A,1],num2str(10^n+1)-48 ) ,'uni',0) 

%optional:
result = cell2mat(result')
```

Comment: the 2nd solution with cumsum is working for me. thanks!